# Replace Hyperlink Texts with File Name from URL for Multiple Links

Tags: vba, url, hyperlink, ms-word

I am trying to replace several hyperlinks in a Word document with the file name taken from the URL.

For example:

*If the first 2 lines in the document are as follows:*

**1. Configure as per instruction sheet   [View Test Procedure]**

**2. Label as per instruction sheet   [View Test Procedure]**

*Where the first [View Test Procedure] is a hyperlink that contains the following URL:* 
http://google.com/Instructional/GMO-M0588/GMO-M0588.pdf

*The second [View Test Procedure] contains the following URL:* 
http://google.com/Instructional/GMO-M0588/GMO-M0578.pdf

How do I replace the hyperlink in the document with just the file name:

GMO-M0588.pdf

GMO-M0578.pdf

So the end result would look like:

**1. Configure as per instruction sheet - GMO-M0588.pdf**

**2. Label as per instruction sheet - GMO-M0578.pdf**

This is what I have come up with so far, which will replace all the hyperlinks with the URL throughout the entire document, but it does not replace it with just the .pdf information.

```
Sub ReplaceHyperlinks()

Dim doc As Document

Dim link, i

Loop through all open documents.

For Each doc In Application.Documents

    Loop through all hyperlinks.

    For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count

            doc.Hyperlinks(i).TextToDisplay = doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address  

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just simply create a User Defined Function that will get the file name form Hyperlinks. Something like,

```
Function GetFileName(tmpStr As String) As String
'******************************************************************************
'   Gets the FileName from the path.
' Eg: ? getFileName("http://google.com/Instructional/GMO-M0588/GMO-M0588.pdf")
'     GMO-M0588.pdf
'******************************************************************************
    GetFileName = Mid(tmpStr, InStrRev(tmpStr, "/") + 1)
End Function
```

The reason I use it in a Function, is just to make it usable almost anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

I guess I am still a little confused on how to put that into a Sub that can be tied to a Command Button. Ideally, I just want to have a single button someone clicks and it automatically replaces all the hyperlinks at once.

(I haven't used VBA in years, so I am pretty rusty)

Comment: You can use the same function you currently have `ReplaceHyperlinks` and instead of `doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address` you can call the function `GetFileName(doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address)`

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help.